# Java Servlet test on CloudFoundry

Tags: servlets

Could anyone please help me?

Locally, on my mahcine I am running Tomcat 8.

I have used Eclipse to create a very very very simple Java Servlet by reading some online tutorials, Here's the code:

```
    package com.theopentutorials.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")
    public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public HelloWorldServlet() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Hello World");
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doGet(request, response);
        }

    }
```

I am successfully running this servlet on my machine and can access it fine from other machines in the same domain.

My web browser simply displays the string "Hello World" as expected.

So, now I'd like to push it to CloudFoundry.

So I use eclipse to export as a WAR file. Fine.

Next to CloudFoundry and I execute the following:

cf push Karry -p FirstServlet.war

All works fine. I see CloudFoundry installing java buildpacks etc. Finally it says App Started OK.

So now I browse to the url provided and I get:

[image: Error]

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,
Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the **/HelloWorldServlet** endpoint? This is where I would look for this servlet, as defined in the code in

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm not sure how I do that. After executing cf push command I just use the url provided in the response - e.g. my-app.shared-domain.com. How do I make use of the /HeloWorldServelet endpoint? Thanks, Mitch.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for you help.